# local sites not loading in acceptable time

Tags: localhost, load-time

Not sure if this is a good SO question. Please advise if not.

So, I've had Apache2.2 and some local sites set up for a really long time. Suddenly, they don't want to load. I get spinning wheels and EVENTUALLY they load but, I would think localhost should load pretty quickly. They always used to.

The only change I've made recently is that, last week, I started rewriting/redesigning one of the sites. I wanted to make sure I was working with a certain codebase, so I actually moved the code out of the root directory, hit it in the browser, saw it was nonexistent, put the new code in and reloaded the browser. It took longer than expected to load stuff up but then it got moving and I continued coding and seeing changes as expected, etc.

Then, I shut down last night since I was away. I started up the machine tonight and have been having these issues all night - on ALL the locally hosted sites!

I've restarted Apache a couple times and it hasn't helped much. My Task Manager claims I'm at over 40% with Firefox eating up nearly 300MB of memory.

All external sites are loading just fine.

Thoughts as to what might be causing this and where to look next?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm noticing that it's taking the images longer to load than the text. Semi-expected, but figured I'd mention it in case it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

My error and access logs were a bit messed up so it took a little digging (and reorganizing) but it finally showed me that it was trying to access a jrun executable that no longer existed. Thing is, that JRUN was removed a long time ago and the httpd.conf file was confusing me since it looks different based on whether I look at it from my personal profile or the Admin profile, so I wasn't seeing the whole picture. I thought the one I saw in Admin was the accurate one since I can only control Apache from there, but, for some reason, it was accessing the other one. (This is whole other problem, but that's a different story.)

Once I realized this and commented out the old JRUN code, the sites load immediately.

Thanks, all, for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of things, from antivirus to slow queries.

Check your resource usage, check your database queries, maybe increase the number of connections for your apache ...

Comment: Thanks, but it's a static php site - no queries. I'm also literally the ONLY one who can access it since it's local.

Comment: Antivirus ? Did you check your resource usage (CPU, Disk, Memory) ?

Comment: Just figured it out!  See answer I'm about to post.